# Possible to express the diagonal matrix $D=\tiny\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{matrix}\right)$ as function of $3\times3$ identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is possible to express the diagonal matrix
$$D=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{matrix}\right)$$
as function of $3\times3$ identity matrix? For example, isn't possible to express it as sum of $3\times3$ identity matrices. This is not an exercise but I would like to know if diagonal matrices can be written, in some way, as a function of identity matrices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just identity matrices, or can other elements be involved?

Comment: what operations do you allow in the function ?

Comment: Just identity matrices, and the operations admitted are whatsoever.

Comment: You need to make up some rules. Otherwise, the operation that sends the identity matrix to your $D$ is the one your are looking for.

Comment: I guess the answer is no with the *regular* operators. all of the operator( $+,-,*, / , power$ you will stay with x*Id. elsewhere you can invent opertaor to do what you need

Comment: Is it allowd to use series? Smth. like $\sin I$

Comment: $f(x)=Dx$ or $f(x)=xD$ )))

Comment: $f(I)=f(1)I\ne D$.

Comment: @A.G. I don't get...are you referring to Michael's comment? I mean $f(I)=D$?!

Comment: @user190080 No, sorry for being unclear. I am referring to [these matrix functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what you are looking for. By Cayley Hamilton , D is the solution to $$A^3 -6IA^2+11IA-6I=0    $$ , where $A$ is any $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: It looks like the opposite - expressing the identity as a function of $D$.

Comment: I was trying to do a sort of function $f( A, Id)$ with $D$ the solution to $f=0$ so I can maybe use a version of the implicit function theorem to make $D$ "locally" a function of $A,I$..

Answer (score 0):

All the eigenvalues of $f(I)$ equal $f(1)$, while $D$ has three distinct eigenvalues, hence the answer is negative.